# Automatically Create Insert Statements to Fill Junction Table in a Pre-Created DB

Tags: android, perl, sqlite

For a simple android app I'm creating as a teaching tool for myself (for using relational dbs/SQL among other things - pardon the simplicity of the question if you will). I'm pre-creating a sqlite db to ship with the application. I'm doing this based on the following [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351195/distribute-db-with-apk).

I've got two tables with a many to many relationship and a junction table to define those relationships as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE Names (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
                    name TEXT
                   );

CREATE TABLE Categories (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
                         category TEXT
                        );

CREATE TABLE Name_Category (name_id INTEGER,
                            category_id INTEGER,
                            PRIMARY KEY (name_id, category_id),
                            foreign key (name_id) references Names(_id),
                            foreign key (category_id) references Categories(_id) 
                           );
```

I've got sets of insert statements to fill the Names and Categories tables. I'm now faced with the task of filling the junction table. I'm sure that I could create the insert statements by hand by looking up the ids of the names and categories that I want to match, but that seems a bit silly.

In order to automatically create the insert statements for the junction table, I imagine that I could create a script based on a set of name and category pairs that will search for the appropriate ids and dump an insert statement. (I came up with this as I was asking the question and will research it. Don't you love it when that happens?)

Does anybody have any suggestions for ways to do this?

**EDIT** I added the foreign keys because, as pointed out below, they'll help maintain integrity between the tables.

**EDIT #2** To solve this, I created a simple Perl script that would take a text file with name - category pairs and dump them out into another file with the appropriate SQL statements.

The name - category text file has a format as follows:

```
'Name' 'Category'
```

The Perl script looks like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open (my $name_category_pair_file, "<", "name_category.txt") or die "Can't open name_category.txt: $!";
open (my $output_sql_file, ">", "load_name_category_junction_table.sqlite") or die "Can't open load_name_category_junction_table.sqlite: $!";

while (<$name_category_pair_file>) {
    if (/('[a-zA-Z ]*') ('[a-zA-Z ]*')/) {
        my $sql_statement = "INSERT INTO Name_Category VALUES (
                             (SELECT _id FROM Names WHERE name = $1),
                             (SELECT _id FROM Categories WHERE category = $2))\;\n\n";

        print $output_sql_file $sql_statement;
    }
}

close $name_category_pair_file or die "$name_category_pair_file: $!";
close $output_sql_file or die "$output_sql_file: $!";
```

Comment: There are some solutions. 1. whenever names or categories inserts, insert name_category manually. 2. batch processing (i don't think this solution works well) 3. using trigger (http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html ) .

Comment: I'm not sure trigger works well in android. but in general purpose, trigger is good solution for such requirement.

Comment: Thanks for the trigger suggestion. I'll take a look into how they work and how well they work in android.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this insert in your script or code (replacing the strings or using `?`):

```
insert into Name_Category values(
   (select _id from Categories where category='CAT1'),
   (select _id from Names where name='NAME1'));
```

Also, you can alter the `Name_Category` table to constraint on the values that can be inserted and/or deleted:

```
CREATE TABLE Name_Category ( name_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
   category_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (name_id, category_id),
   foreign key (name_id) references Names(_id),
   foreign key (category_id) references Categories(_id));
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I'll definitely add the foreign keys to the junction table. I'll also take a look at the syntax of how the inserts work with the ? character.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What you suggested is useful for my learning. The reason I haven't accepted it is because I was looking for suggestions for how best to pre-fill the junction table before including in the app or confirmation that a script is a good way to go. What are your thoughts?

Comment: Well, the first part of my answer address that. Have the list of pairs in a file and run a script to populate the table with this insert.

Answer (score 0):

create two main tables first and then create a junction table in which primary key of both main tables will be available as foreign key.. Primary key of junction table will be union 
of **primary key of first and second main table**.

Create trigger now to automatically insert into junction table...

Also don't forget to create table with cascade deletion and cascade updatation so that any value updated or deleted in main tables will be automatically reflected in junction table

Comment: You'll notice that many of your suggestions are there already. Thanks for the triggers suggestion.